# Any more optimized way to handle the mutiple slices in react components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have created slices for POST and GET operation -

```
export const getAllAnnotationType = createAsyncThunk<IGetAllAnnotationType>(
  "annotationType/getAll",
  async (annotationType, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await Services.get("/globalAnnotationTypes");
      return response.data.slice().reverse() as IGetAllAnnotationType;
    } catch (err) {
      const error = err as any;
      return rejectWithValue(error?.response?.data);
    }
  }
);

export const createAnnotationType = createAsyncThunk<
  ICreateAnnotationType,
  { name: string; des: string }
>("annotationType/create", async (annotationType, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const { name, des } = annotationType;
    const response = await Services.post("/globalAnnotationTypes", {
      name,
      des,
    });
    return response.data as ICreateAnnotationType;
  } catch (err) {
    const error = err as any;
    return rejectWithValue(error?.response?.data);
  }
});
```

I have created one common slice for both of the operations.

And I am using these in my react components like this -

```
useEffect(() => {
    switch (typeLoader) {
      case 'pending':
        setLoader(true);
        break;

      case 'succeeded':
        if (getAllData) {
          dispatch(resetAnnotationType());
          setLoader(false);
          setRows(getAllData);
        }
        if (createData) {
          showToast();
          dispatch(getAllAnnotationType());
          setNoticeMsg(createData);
        }
        break;

      case 'failed':
        showToast();
    }
  }, [typeLoader]);
```

I am looking for more optimized way to use them in react components. In future, I will have DELETE and PUT operations, and I will have to use more conditions inside 'succeeded' state. Any other way I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to handle fetching data is [Redux Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview).
It creates slices. You can custom the fetch function if needed, and you are given hooks, to work with in the component directly.
You can also cache the fetched data. A simple example of use can be (in the component):

```
const {data, isLoading, error} = useGetDataQuery(args) //if you needed args
```

If you had further questions about sharing cached data across the application, you can comment here, I'll be happy to share how I solved my problem (using something called `fixedCacheQuery`).

Even though you can find the boilerplate on the website, if you needed, let me know and I will edit this response to share the boilerplate as I write and use it.